# How can the behavior of InterpolationOrder->0 be controlled?

Tags: plotting, functions, interpolation

In `ListPlot` and `Interpolation`, the option `InterpolationOrder->0` uses two different conventions.

`Interpolation` gives the y-value from the nearest *greater* x-value.

```
Plot[Quiet@Interpolation[{{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}},InterpolationOrder->0][x],{x,-1,3}]
```

[image]

`ListLinePlot` gives the y-value from the nearest *smaller* x-value.

```
ListLinePlot[{{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}},InterpolationOrder->0,PlotRange->{{-1,3},All}]
```

[image]

How can I make `Interpolation` use the `ListPlot` convention?

Comment: Great question +1. I should have asked this myself.

Comment: It appears that in version 10.2, [ListStepPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStepPlot.html) will offer an explicit option to control this behavior.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can negate the x-values in the input data and then negate the trial x-value.

```
Plot[Quiet@Interpolation[{{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}}.DiagonalMatrix[{-1,1}],InterpolationOrder->0][-x],{x,-1,3}]
```

[image]

This is a bit clumsy.

Comment: "A bit clumsy," but very fast.

Answer (score 21):

The question made me wonder about zero-order interpolations.  It's hardly clear which is the right way.  When I tried to figure out why `ListLinePlot` would use a different `Interpolation`, I noticed it didn't seem to use an `Interpolation` for orders `0` or `1` at all, but did it the simple way which you might use by hand: connect the dots.  This was probably done for speed, and it is an important speed-up for linear interpolations.  For a zero-order plot, there are at least two choices, "up/down and over" or "over and up/down" -- like walking around a block.  Somehow the implementation for `ListLinePlot` chooses the way that does not agree with the choice of `Interpolation`.  I tend to favor consistency, but this way there is a convenient way to get both plots.

It turns out there are three common zero-order interpolations.  Of the two we see in the question, one sort of take the **floor** of the first coordinate, the datum whose first coordinate is nearest but less than or equal to an input `x`; the second, takes the **ceiling** with respect to the data in a similar way.  The third method chooses the datum whose first coordinate is **absolutely nearest** `x`, like Voronoi cells.  Indeed, [`ListPlot3D` seems to use this method](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot3D.html#130288802).

This third way led me to think that `Nearest` could be used to make step functions for all three ways that are faster than `Piecewise` on large data sets.  They are called `stepFloor` (like `Interpolation`), `stepCeiling` (like `ListLinePlot`) and `stepNearest` and each returns a function.

```
Plot[stepFloor[steps][x],
     stepCeiling[steps][x]},
 {x, -1, 11},
 PlotStyle -> {
     Directive[Thick, Dashed],
     Thickness[Medium]}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point@Transpose@{Range@Length@steps, steps}}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]

Plot[stepNearest[steps][x],
 {x, -1, 11}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[Medium]}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point@Transpose@{Range@Length@steps, steps}}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Functions**

The three are implemented via the general `stepFunction[stepFn_, steps_]` that evaluates when applied to a numeric argument `x` (that is, the `PatternTest` `x_?NumericQ` prevents evaluation on symbolic argument `x` and avoids error messages from `NearestFunction`).  For whatever reason, I wanted to make a decent interface, and I was led to incorporating intermediate, auxiliary functions.  Perhaps there's a shorter way, but it takes a long time to write something short.

One of the helper functions is the intermediate `stepFunction[nearest, steps, {test, next}]`, which can summarized as follows: it takes the `nearest` value in `steps`, and if `test` returns `True`, then it returns the `next` value instead.  The argument `nearest` is a [`NearestFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NearestFunction.html), and `test` and `next` are functions as well.  The function `nearest` returns the index of the nearest datum and the desired one will be this one or the one next to it returned by `next`.  In `stepCeiling` for instance, `test` is [`Less`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Greater.html) and `next` is `#-1 &`, or the previous element in `steps`, In other words, `test` indicates that `nearest` did *not* return the desired value and that it should be adjusted by `next`.  (I waver whether the sense of `test` should be reversed -- a matter of taste, perhaps.)

There is also an intermediate step to sort the data `steps`, except in `stepNearest` where it is unnecessary.

```
ClearAll[stepFunction, stepCeiling, stepFloor, stepNearest];

stepFunction[stepFn_, steps_][x_?NumericQ] := stepFn[steps, x];
stepFunction[nearest_NearestFunction, steps_, {test_, next_}] := 
  stepFunction[
   With[{nearIDX = First@nearest@#2},
     If[test[#2, #1[[nearIDX, 1]]],
      #1[[Clip[next@nearIDX, {1, Length@#1}], 2]],
      #1[[nearIDX, 2]]]] &,
   steps
   ];
Format[stepFunction[args__]] := Shallow[HoldForm[stepFunction][args], {3, 2}];

stepFloor[steps_?VectorQ] := stepFloor[Transpose @ {N@Range@Length@steps, steps}, True];
stepFloor[steps_?MatrixQ] := stepFloor[Sort @ steps, True];
stepFloor[steps_?MatrixQ, True] := (* True => sorted *)
  stepFunction[Nearest[First /@ steps -> Automatic], steps, {Greater, # + 1 &}];

stepCeiling[steps_?VectorQ] := stepCeiling[Transpose @ {N@Range@Length@steps, steps}, True];
stepCeiling[steps_?MatrixQ] := stepCeiling[Sort @ steps, True];
stepCeiling[steps_?MatrixQ, True] := (* True => sorted *)
  stepFunction[Nearest[First /@ steps -> Automatic], steps, {Less, # - 1 &}];

stepNearest[steps_?VectorQ] := stepNearest[Transpose @ {N@Range@Length@steps, steps}];
stepNearest[steps_?MatrixQ] := With[{nf = Nearest[Rule @@ Transpose@steps]},
  stepFunction[First @ nf @ #2 &, {}]];
```

*Efficiency*

**Time**: As for speed, Mr.Wizard's `Piecewise` solution `interp0` starts out about a bit faster than the corresponding `stepCeiling`, but as the length of the data grows, `stepCeiling` quickly becomes markedly faster.  On the other hand, `Plot` recognizes `Piecewise` and the advantage in plotting `interp0` lasts up until the length of the data exceeds a couple hundred.  `Plot` generally produces a better-looking graph with `interp0` than with `stepCeiling`.

In this table, the time to construct the function once plus the time to evaluate each function `1000` times on data of length `10^i`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The result on lists of pairs is similar:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Space**:
Here are the `ByteCount`s of the two functions and `Interpolation` on data of size `10^i`, as well as the ratios between `interp0` and `stepCeiling` (`i/s`) and between `Interpolation` and `stepCeiling` (`I/s`).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Timing code*

```
SeedRandom[2];
times = Table[
  dat = RandomReal[999, 10^i];
  {SeedRandom[i]; 
   First @ AbsoluteTiming[
      Module[{f = Function[x, Evaluate@interp0[dat, x]]}, Do[f@RandomReal[999], {1000}]]],
   SeedRandom[i]; 
   First @ AbsoluteTiming[
      Module[{f = stepCeiling[dat]}, Do[f@RandomReal[999], {1000}]]]},
   {i, 5}]
```

**Plotting Manhattan Walks**

While not precisely part of the OP's question, the difference between the plots of the methods of interpolation was raised.  It seems that `ListLinePlot` with `InterpolationOrder -> 0` simply constructs a "Manhattan path" through the points, that is, an alternating sequence of horizontal and vertical line segments.  The function `manhattanWalk` below constructs such a path; the form `manhattanWalk[list, Horizontal]` begins with a `Horizontal` segment and matches what `ListLinePlot` does.

```
manhattanWalk[pts_, Left | Right | Horizontal | ___] := 
  Most @ Flatten[
    Transpose[{{#1, RotateLeft[#1]}, {#2, #2}} & @@ Transpose[pts], {1, 3, 2}], {{2, 3}}];
manhattanWalk[pts_, Up | Down | Vertical] := 
  Most @ Flatten[
    Transpose[{{#1, #1}, {#2, RotateLeft@#2}} & @@ Transpose[pts], {1, 3, 2}], {{2, 3}}];
```

We can see that `LineLinePlot` produces an equivalent plot to `manhattanWalk` (aside from styling), even when the points are not sorted.

```
SeedRandom[2];
data = RandomReal[10, {5, 2}];

Graphics[{Opacity[0.6], Line @ manhattanWalk[data], Red, 
  PointSize@Medium, Point[data], Blue, PointSize@Large, Point @ First @ data},
  ImageSize -> 250, Frame -> True]

Show[
 ListLinePlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 250],
 PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is not the same as `Interpolation` at all, which sorts the `data` (and does a `manhattanWalk` beginning with vertical move:

```
Module[{f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]},
 Plot[f[x], Evaluate[(First@f["Domain"] + {-0.01, 0})~Prepend~x], Frame -> True]]

Graphics[{Opacity[0.6], Line @ manhattanWalk[Sort @ data, Vertical],
  Red, PointSize@Medium, Point[data], Blue, PointSize@Large, Point @ First @ Sort @ data},
 ImageSize -> 250, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I've used `Nearest` [myself](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/872/121) for the centered version, and I tried to use it for this problem as well but I failed.  I don't have time now but I'll be *very* interested to see how you pulled this off.

Comment: Michael, what do you think of my new answer?

Comment: `ListPlot3D` only appears to use nearest zero-order interpolation (like Voronoi cells) when given explicit x,y coordinates. When given only height values, it appears to use the floor method (and consequently does not display all the data).

Answer (score 10):

Here is a refinement of @MichaelE2's answer where the basic difference is that I vectorize all operations so that it is fast when given a list of data. It is similar to my [LeftNeighbor](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154942/45431) function from [Given an ordered set S, find the points in S corresponding to another list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154893/45431). Also, I will use [`Left`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Left) and [`Right`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Right) instead of [`Floor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Floor) and [`Ceiling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ceiling) to indicate the direction the step extends to. This is analogous to the [`ListStepPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStepPlot) nomenclature. Here is the basic code:

**StepFunction**

```
StepFunction[data_, pos_:Left]:=Module[{sdata,nf},
    sdata=Sort@data;
    nf = Nearest[sdata[[All,1]]->"Index"];
    StepFunction[
        nf,
        sdata[[All,1]],
        sdata[[All,2]],
        Replace[pos,{Left->{0,1}, _->{-1,0}}]
    ]
]

StepFunction[nf_NearestFunction, x_, y_, clip_][pt_List] := With[
    {near = nf[pt][[All,1]]},

    y[[Clip[near + Clip[Sign[Subtract[pt, x[[near]]]], clip], {1, Length[x]}]]]
]
StepFunction[nf_NearestFunction, x_, y_, clip_][pt_?NumericQ]:=With[
    {near=First@nf[pt]},

    y[[Clip[near + Clip[Sign[Subtract[pt, x[[near]]]], clip], {1, Length[x]}]]]
]
```

**Formatting**

And here is a formatting rule so that `StepFunction` looks nice:

```
MakeBoxes[s:StepFunction[_, x_, y_, clip_], StandardForm] ^:= Module[
    {left, g},
    left = MatchQ[clip, {0, 1}];
    g = Graphics[
        {
        Directive[Opacity[1.`], RGBColor[0.4`,0.5`,0.7`], AbsoluteThickness[1]],
        Line[{{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{2,1}}],
        PointSize[Medium],
        If[left, Point[{{1,0}, {2,1}}], Point[{{0,0},{1,1}}]]
        },
        Frame->True,FrameTicks->None,
        PlotRangePadding->{Scaled[.15], Scaled[.2]},
        AspectRatio->1,
        ImageSize->{Automatic,30}
    ];
    BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
        StepFunction,
        s,
        g,
        {
            BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Data points: ", Length[x]}, StandardForm],
            BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Domain: ", x[[{1,-1}]]},StandardForm],
            BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Range: ", MinMax[y]},StandardForm]
        },
        {
        },
        StandardForm,
        "Interpretable"->True
    ]
]
```

**Examples**

Here are a couple simple examples:

```
left = StepFunction[{{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}}]
right = StepFunction[{{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}}, Right]
```

[image]

Notice how the summary box indicates the direction of the step (the default is to the left, just as it is for [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction)). Here are a couple plots:

```
Plot[left[t], {t, 0, 4}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[Thread[{{1,2,3}, left[{1,2,3}]}]]}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[right[t], {t, 0, 4}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[Thread[{{1,2,3}, right[{1,2,3}]}]]}]
```

[image]

**Speed**

Finally, a speed comparison. Here is the sample dataset with half a million elements used by @MrWizard:

```
SeedRandom[2]
dat=RandomReal[999,{500000,2}];

if = Interpolation[dat, InterpolationOrder->0]; //AbsoluteTiming
sf = StepFunction[dat]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.651699, Null}
>
> {0.12601, Null}

So, creating the `StepFunction` is faster than creating an [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction). Now, for some random test data:

```
test = RandomReal[{1, 999}, 10^6];

r1 = if[test]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = sf[test]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {1.69502, Null}
>
> {0.131804, Null}
>
> True

We can perform a similar comparison with right steps versus the accepted answer:

```
if = Interpolation[dat . DiagonalMatrix[{-1, 1}], InterpolationOrder->0]; //AbsoluteTiming
sf = StepFunction[dat, Right]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.661638, Null}
>
> {0.131311, Null}

```
r1 = if[-test]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = sf[test]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {1.7282, Null}
>
> {0.129593, Null}
>
> True

So, zeroth order interpolations using [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) are quite a bit faster than using [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation).

Comment: For users of Mathematica versions prior to 11.1, just edit the second line of the StepFunction to: 
      nf = Nearest[ Thread[sdata[[All, 1]] -> Range[Length[sdata[[All, 1]]]]]];

Comment: @Dephine or replace "Index" with Automatic.

Comment: Right! Do you know why using Evaluate on a list of StepFunctions in a Plot leads to numerous errors? Any way to avoid them?

Comment: @Delphine The StepFunction as I've defined it only works for numeric input, and won't work when given a symbol argument. I added a pattern restriction to avoid this.

Comment: @CarlWoll When implementing StepFunction in the Workbench I get the warning message: "The local variable, a, is not used." making reference to MakeBoxes[s:StepFunction[a_,...  Any comments on this?

Comment: @ArielSepulveda I removed the symbol.

Answer (score 9):

It has occurred to me that I was thinking about this problem all wrong:
**We merely need a binary search within the index list.**

```
SeedRandom[2]
dat = RandomInteger[999, {35, 2}];

ListLinePlot[SortBy[dat, {First}], InterpolationOrder -> 0, Epilog -> Point@dat]

Needs["Combinatorica`"]
Module[{d1, d2},
 {d1, d2} = SortBy[dat, {First}]\[Transpose];
 Plot[d2[[Floor @ BinarySearch[d1, x]]], {x, 0, 999}, Epilog -> Point@dat]
]
```

[image]
[image]

A binary search can also be quite efficient.  I will use Leonid's [`bsearchMin`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2371/121) code, compiled:

```
bsInterp0[dat_] :=
  Module[{d1, d2, cf},
   {d1, d2} = SortBy[dat, {First}]\[Transpose];
   With[{list = d1},
    cf = Compile[{elem},
      Module[{n0 = 1, n1 = Length[list], m = 0},
       While[n0 <= n1, m = Floor[(n0 + n1)/2];
        If[list[[m]] == elem, While[list[[m]] == elem, m++];
         Return[m - 1]];
        If[list[[m]] < elem, n0 = m + 1, n1 = m - 1]];
       If[list[[m]] < elem, m, m - 1]]
    ]
   ];
   d2[[cf[#]]] &
  ];
```

Timings:

```
SeedRandom[2]
dat = RandomReal[999, {500000, 2}];

if = Interpolation[dat, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
bsf = bsInterp0[dat];
scf = stepCeiling[dat];  (* Michael's function *)

if  /@ Range[0, 999, 0.01] // Timing // First
bsf /@ Range[0, 999, 0.01] // Timing // First
```

> 0.094
>
> 0.514

On a set with half a million elements it is ~5.5X slower than `InterpolatingFunction`.

Compared to Michael's `stepCeiling` with the same data it is ~45X faster:

```
bsf /@ Range[0, 999, 0.05] // Timing // First
scf /@ Range[0, 999, 0.05] // Timing // First
```

> 0.1062
>
> 4.758

Comment: Ouch! that's fast. +1

Answer (score 8):

Since I can't think of anything else here is a method using a `Piecewise` object.  For a limited number of points its quite fast but it slows down as the number increases.  It's not a replacement for `InterpolatingFunction` but it can be handy at times.

```
SeedRandom[2]
dat = RandomInteger[999, {35, 2}];

ListLinePlot[SortBy[dat, {First}], InterpolationOrder -> 0]
Plot[interp0[dat, x], {x, 0, 999}, Exclusions -> None, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]
[image]

Also works with one-dimensional data:

```
SeedRandom[2]
dat = RandomReal[99, 35];

ListLinePlot[dat, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
Plot[interp0[dat, x], {x, 0, 36}, Exclusions -> None, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]
[image]

The optional second argument specifies the variable to use; it defaults to Formal x.

#### Code:

```
interp0[dat_?VectorQ, sym_: \[FormalX]] :=
 {Range[2, Length@dat], Most@dat}\[Transpose] //
  Piecewise[{#2, sym < #} & @@@ #, Last @ dat] &  

interp0[dat_, sym_: \[FormalX]] :=
 Module[{d},
  d = SortBy[dat, {First}];
  d[[All, 1]] = RotateLeft[d[[All, 1]]];
  Piecewise[{#2, sym < #} & @@@ d, d[[-1, 2]]]
 ]
```

Comment: +1 Nice and simple. One of the nice things about `Piecewise` is that, if desired, `Plot` won't connect the steps when the `Exclusions` option is omitted.