# For-loop not working as I expect

Tags: functions, data, broken-code

I want to do this:

- When `10 <= t < 130`, give `t -> 1`;
- When `130 <= t<300`, give `t->3`;
- When `300 <= t< 1000`, give `t -> 4`;
- When `1000 <= t < 2000`, give `t -> 5`;

My code is this:

```
data = {10, 130, 300, 1000, 2000};
fun[t_] := Part[data, t];
comf[s_] := For[t = 1, t <= 4, t++, If[fun[t] <= s < fun[t+1], Print[t]]];
```

I could get this:

```
comf[110]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

```
comf[1300]
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

But when I evaluate this

```
comf[110] + 100
```

I didn’t get the right result, rather I got this:

> ```
> 100 + Null
> ```

I would like to know how I could fix this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this t increments by 1 (or constant amount) as suggested by code (I only raise this the question does 1,3,4,5) then you use `UnitStep` and decided what you want to do outside the domain.

```
data = {10, 130, 300, 1000, 2000};
func[t_] := Total[UnitStep[t - #] & /@ data]
```

Visualizing:

```
Plot[func[x], {x, 0, 3000}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
Mr. Wizard has explained in comment how this can be simplified. Mr Wizard's advice:

```
mrwmod[u_]:=Tr@UnitStep[u-data]
```

Comment: Quite an interesting approach.  Incidentally you don't need `Map`; I would write: `func[t_] := Tr @ UnitStep[t - data]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you. I always learn something. Will edit.

Answer (score 7):

For your existing code you need to [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html) the value of `t` rather than `Print`ing it:

```
data = {10, 130, 300, 1000, 2000};
fun[t_] := Part[data, t];
comf[s_] := For[t = 1, t <= 4, t++, If[fun[t] <= s < fun[t + 1], Return @ t]]
```

Now:

```
comf[110] + 100
```

> ```
> 101
> ```

However, this code is very much not in the recommended style of *Mathematica* programming.  See [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121) for some examples.

### Alternatives

Perhaps the most direct simplification of the above code is to use `Do` in place of the manually incremented variable in `For`:

```
comf[s_] := Do[If[fun[t] <= s < fun[t + 1], Return @ t], {t, 4}]
```

You could also write it as a self-contained [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html) function:

```
f1 =
  Piecewise[
    {{1, 10 <= # < 130},
     {2, 130 <= # < 300},
     {3, 300 <= # < 1000},
     {4, 1000 <= # < 2000}}
  ] &;

f1 /@ {5, 17, 200, 300, 5000}
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 0}
> ```

(The second argument of `Piecewise` can be used to determine what is returned when none of the conditions match; the default is zero.)

If you prefer to keep your values in `data` you might use something like [`LengthWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LengthWhile.html):

```
f2[s_] := LengthWhile[data, # <= s &]

f2 /@ {5, 17, 200, 300, 5000}
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 5}
> ```

A very efficient method is [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html) with an [`InterpolationOrder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolationOrder.html) of zero:

```
f3 = Interpolation[MapIndexed[{#, #2[[1]] - 1} &, data], InterpolationOrder -> 0];
```

Note however that this does not produce the same less-equal behavior as the others; it also warns you when the output is outside the interpolation range:

```
f3 /@ {5, 17, 200, 300, 5000}
```

> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {5} lies outside the range
>   of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>
>
> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {5000} lies outside the
>   range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be
>   used. >>
>
> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 2, 4}
> ```

See: [How can the behavior of InterpolationOrder->0 be controlled?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30055/121)

---

[rasher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/rasher) posted a method using [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interval.html) and [`IntervalMemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntervalMemberQ.html) which I like, but which I believe can be written more efficiently.  Specifically the inefficiencies are:

- computing the `Interval` list every time the function is called
- not using the listability of `IntervalMemberQ`

We can address both points with this:

```
With[{intv = Interval /@ Partition[data, 2, 1]},
 f4 = Pick[index, IntervalMemberQ[intv, #]] &;
]

index = {1, 3, 4, 5};

f4 /@ {5, 30, 400, 5000}
```

> ```
> {{}, {1}, {4}, {}}
> ```

Comment: What a nice analysis. +1 on using interpolation!

Answer (score 2):

Neat answers! My twisted take on something different, a generic function that accepts the data and indexes and returns an indexer:

```
data = {10, 130, 300, 1000, 2000};
index = {1, 3, 4, 5};

test = Function[arg, 
   Extract[index, 
    Position[
     Interval /@ 
      Partition[data, 2, 1], _?(IntervalMemberQ[#, arg] &)]]];

test[#] & /@ {5, 30, 400, 5000}
```

(*  {{}, {1}, {4}, {}}  *)

Note that indices are bracketed, out-of-range being empty. Can of course trivially be turned into a function that accepts the data/indices directly.

Comment: You have made a mistake that I see surprisingly frequently: you added a `Function` where it is not needed; `test` is *already* a Function; just use `test /@ {5, 30, 400, 5000}`.  Also, and more importantly, the computation of the `Interval` list is performed for each call to `test`, which is inefficient.  Nevertheless I like the idea of using `IntervalMemberQ` so +1.  I shall attempt to write a more efficient version.

Comment: Habit. And of course, this was just an example, my allusion to a function accepting the data/indices was bread-crumbs on the path toward a proper implementation. Shame interval testing is a bit sluggish: probably better to generate a `Piecewise` function as the result, but I like to use orphan functions occasionally.

Comment: Actually I think it will be reasonably fast in the listable form (see my updated answer).  I intend to add timings for all methods later tonight.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Color me surprised that you took my hunchback code and turned it into the handsome prince ;-). Your comments and answers always enlighten! I look forward to the timings.