# How to make multiple if statements?

Tags: code-review

I know Mathematica's if format is

```
If[test, then result, else alternative]
```

For example, this

```
y:=If[RandomReal[]<0.2, 1, 3.14]
```

would take a random real number between $0$ and $1$, and evaluate it. If it's less than $0.2$, it'll map `y` to $1$, otherwise, it'll map `y` to $3.13$.

I would like to extend this to multiple intervals, short of writing out multiply nested `If` statements, how can this be done?  Can this be done automatically?

For example, if `x := RandomReal[]`, I want to map to `1`, if `x < 0.1`, 3 if `0.1 <= x < 0.2`, 19.1 if `0.2 <= x < 0.34`, or 7.7 if `x >= 0.34`.

Comment: Maybe Piecewise？

Comment: Also can use `Which`.

Comment: The above, and of course you can nest If.

Answer (score 9):

There are several functions and methods available which different strengths and limitations that can guide your choice.  Among them:

### [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html)

Here combined with [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) to pass a single `RandomReal[]` value among the tests:

```
y := Which[
       # < 0.1,         1,
       0.1 <= # < 0.2,  3,
       0.2 <= # < 0.34, 19.1,
       True,            7.7
     ] & @ RandomReal[]
```

Which, like `If`, is a flow control construct.  `True` is used to create a default case.  Related to it is:

### [`Switch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html)

The syntax of `Switch` allows us to do without the `Function` since the first argument is only evaluated once, but we must introduce [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) and [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html):

```
y := Switch[RandomReal[],
       x_ /; x < 0.1,          1,
       x_ /; 0.1 <= x < 0.2,   3, 
       x_ /; 0.2 <= x < 0.34,  19.1,
       _,                      7.7
     ]
```

Here the pattern `_` (see [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)) is used to create the default case.  `Switch` is also a flow control function, unlike:

### [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

`Piecewise` is intended as a mathematical function and it therefore often behaves better within a mathematical framework; if the expression is going to be manipulated mathematically it is probably your best starting point.  It has an optional nice looking "2D" input form:

[image]

```
y := \[Piecewise] {
     {1, # < 0.1},
     {3, 0.1 <= # < 0.2},
     {19.1, 0.2 <= # < 0.34},
     {7.7, True}
    } & @ RandomReal[]
```

### [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) and [`IntervalMemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMemberQ.html)

The three methods above are general; however for the given example there are more specialized approaches.  One is to use `Interval`, though it is important to understand that it represents an interval closed on both ends.  Here is one formulation also using [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html); the interval range `{-∞, ∞}` is used for the default case:

```
With[
  {intv = 
    Interval /@ Append[Partition[{0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.34}, 2, 1], {-∞, ∞}]},
  y := First @ Pick[{1, 3, 19.1, 7.7}, IntervalMemberQ[intv, RandomReal[]]]
]
```

### [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html)

Faster when applicable is an [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) as generated by [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html):

```
intfn = Interpolation[{{0.1, 0.2, 0.34, 1*^99}, {1, 3, 19.1, 7.7}}\[Transpose], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0];

y := intfn @ RandomReal[]
```

In the example above I had to use an arbitrary "large number" `1*^99` for the default case as `Infinity` is not accepted.

A [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) of `intfn`:

```
Plot[intfn[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer to your question, but I wanted to point out a better way of coding

```
y:=If[RandomReal[]<0.2,1,3.14]
```

Use [`RandomChoice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice.html), instead, as you can specify the exact probabilities with which each number is chosen:

```
h := RandomChoice[{0.2, 0.8} -> {1, 3.14}]
```

This can be adapted to your second list with something like this

```
x[rngs_ -> vals_] := First@x[rngs -> vals, 1]
x[rngs_ -> vals_, n_] := Block[{ps},
  ps = Flatten[{#, 1 - Total@#}]& @ Differences @ Prepend[0] @ rngs;
  RandomChoice[ps -> vals, n]
] /; Length@vals - 1 == Length@rngs

x[{0.1, 0.2, 0.34} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, 4]
(* {4, 1, 1, 4} *)
```

Obviously, you would not want to recalculate the probability list every time, so you can return a function, instead

```
z[rngs_ -> vals_, n_:1] := Block[{ps},
  ps = Flatten[{#, 1 - Total@#}]& @ Differences @ Prepend[0] @ rngs;
  With[{plst = ps},
    If[n==1,
      RandomChoice[plst -> vals]&,
      RandomChoice[plst -> vals, n]&
    ]
  ]
] /; Length@vals - 1 == Length@rngs
```

Which can then be used to construct your `y`

```
y := Evaluate[z[{0.1, 0.2, 0.34} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}]][]
```

and answers your question, apparently.

Comment: defeat conceded :)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP lol. :)

Comment: Also was thinking of how to specify `{0.1, 0.1, 0.14, 0.66}` for `RandomChoice` when given the ranges `{0.1, 0.2, 0.34, 1}`. That's a long-winded way of writing the inverse function of `Accumulate`

Comment: Not the question that was asked but a good treatment of a possible application. +1

Comment: @LLlAMnYP why yes it is.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard actually, with the last adaptation, I think it answers the OP perfectly, if in a round about manner.

Comment: You're right, I misremembered the wording of the question, thinking that this was merely one example of the general case of nested `If`.  I guess I went in the wrong direction with my answer in that case.  Ah well, hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 2:** Using `WeightedData`, `EmpiricalDistribution`, `Randomvariate`

```
ClearAll[wdF]
wdF[t_, v_, n_: 1] := Module[{d = EmpiricalDistribution[
     WeightedData[v, Differences[Join[{0}, t, {1}]]]]},
  RandomVariate[d, n]]
```

Examples:

```
thresholds = {.1, .2, .34};
values = {1, 3, 19.1, 7.7};   

wdF[thresholds, values]
(* {7.7} *)
wdF[thresholds, values, 10]
(* {1, 7.7, 19.1, 7.7, 7.7, 7.7, 7.7, 19.1, 19.1, 1} *)
```

**Update:** `Fold`ing `If`s

```
ClearAll[foldedIf]
foldedIf[t_, v_][x_] := Module[{args = 
    Reverse@Thread[{Partition[Join[{-∞}, t], 2, 1], Most@v}]},
  Fold[If[# <= x < #2 & @@ #2[[1]], Evaluate@Last@#2, #] &, Last@v, args]]
```

Examples:

```
foldedIf[{t1, t2, t3}, {a, b, c, d}][x]
```

> If[-∞ <= x < t1, a, If[t1 <= x < t2, b, If[t2 <= x < t3, c, d]]]

```
foldedIf[thresholds, values][w]
```

> If[-∞ <= w < 0.1, 1, If[0.1 <= w < 0.2, 3, If[0.2 <= w < 0.34, 19.1, 7.7]]]

```
foldedIf[thresholds, values] /@ RandomReal[1, 5]
(* {7.7, 7.7, 19.1, 7.7, 7.7} *)
```

Two-argument form of `Fold`:

```
ClearAll[feldIf]
feldIf[t_, v_][x_] := Fold[If[# <= x < #2 & @@ #2[[1]], Evaluate@Last@#2, #] &, 
  Prepend[Reverse@ Thread[{Partition[Join[{-∞}, t], 2, 1], Most@v}], Last@v]]

feldIf[{t1, t2, t3}, {a, b, c, d}][x]
```

> If[-∞ <= x < t1, a, If[t1 <= x < t2, b, If[t2 <= x < t3, c, d]]]

---

**Original post:**

```
y := With[{rr = RandomReal[]}, 
  Piecewise[{{1, rr < .1}, {3, .1 <= rr < .2}, {19.1, .2 <= rr < .34}}, 7.7]]

Table[y, {10}]
(* {7.7`, 3, 7.7`, 3, 19.1`, 7.7`, 7.7`, 7.7`, 19.1`, 7.7`} *)
```

A function that constructs a `Piecewise` function given a list of thresholds and a list of values:

```
ClearAll[pwF]
pwF[t_, v_][x_] := Module[{args = Join @@@ 
      Thread[{List /@ v, Partition[Join[{0}, t, {Infinity}], 2, 1]}]},
   Piecewise[{#, #2 <= x < #3} & @@@ args]]
```

Example:

```
thresholds = {.1, .2, .34};
values = {1, 3, 19.1, 7.7};

pwF[thresholds, values]@x
```

> [image]

```
pwF[thresholds, values] /@ RandomReal[1, 10]
(*  {7.7`, 19.1`, 7.7`, 19.1`, 3, 7.7`, 1, 19.1`, 19.1`, 7.7`} *)
```

Comment: darn, you just preempted me with that edit...

Comment: Sorry @Mr.Wizard :)

Comment: No problem; you've got my vote already. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `Interval` for something like this.

E.G., a function that takes as arguments the intervals, what a "hit" in the interval should return, and the target:

```
f1 = Pick[#2, IntervalMemberQ[Interval /@ #1, #3]] &;

f1[{{0, .1}, {.1, .2}, {.2, .3}}, {1, 2, 3}, .23]

(* {3} *)
```

And using this to build a single argument function for a given set of intervals and returns:

```
f2 = f1[{{0, .1}, {.1, .2}, {.2, .3}}, {1, 2, 3}, #] &;

test = RandomReal[1/3, 3]
f2 /@ test

(* 

{0.136326, 0.188152, 0.292161}

{{2}, {2}, {3}} 

*)
```

Take note of how values on boundaries are handled, use `Part` or `First` to filter to your needs.

Comment: beat you to it ;-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Ah, LOL - was that added while I was typing, could have sworn when I glanced at answers was surprised no one had interval.  WIll happily delete if you'd like... BTW - there's a goofy way with `Nearest`...

Comment: Yes, I added it a couple of minutes after my initial post, and before my `Interpolation` addendum.  Please don't feel the need to delete; sometimes a simple one-subject answer is clearer and preferred by the OP.  I was just having some fun with it; my *original* answer was going to include meta-programming but about a minute before I would have posted kguler's `pwF` edit came up so I had to thing of something else useful to add. :-)

Comment: Would the `Nearest` method be similar to what Michael did here?: [(30103)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30103/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Nah - just bisect the intervals as `Partition[...,2,1]` pairs, threading over the desired returns inside the `Nearest` creation. So anything <=the distance to boundary gets a given value. Not *quite* the same result as OP question, but I suppose adding an "undefined" return on the front/back bounds addresses that. Like I said, goofy.