# How can I change the behaviour of InterpolationOrder -> 0?

Tags: interpolation

Consider the following example:

```
Module[{lst, iFn0},
    lst = {{5, 1}, {7, 4}, {12, 5}};
    iFn0 = Interpolation[lst, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
    iFn0[5.25]
];
```

This returns `4`.  Obviously, interpolation has been constructed by "pulling back" the values, as if to say that the correct value for everything up to `7` is the measurement at `7`.

But I would like to construct an interpolation by "pushing forward" the values, so that the correct value in the closed-open interval `[5, 7)` is `1`.  I know that I can cycle the values forward in `lst` and sort of fake the outcome:

```
`lst2 = {{5, 1}, {7, 1}, {12, 4}, {12.01, 5}}`
```

But this is problematic, because then `iFn0[7] = 1` and I need it to be `4`.

Is there a setting for `InterpolationOrder -> 0` that will do the interpolation in the desired way?

Comment: You can slide the `y` values one position to the right, and  double up the value on the left end. `slideValues[pts_] := Module[{yvals = RotateRight[pts[[All, 2]]]},
  yvals[[1]] = yvals[[2]];
  Interpolation[Transpose[{pts[[All, 1]], yvals}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0]]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I did mention in my post that I can "fake" the desired outcome by doing just what you suggest.  The problem, however, is that the interpolation function has the incorrect values at the points themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "reverse x axis"

```
lst = {{5, 1}, {7, 4}, {12, 5}};
iFn0 = Interpolation[{-#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ lst, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0];
f[x_] := iFn0[-x];

f /@ {5.25, 7}
(*{1, 4} *)
```

Or the same can be achieved with:

```
InterpolationR[l_] := Interpolation[{-#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ l, 
     InterpolationOrder -> 0][-#] &;
a = InterpolationR[lst];
a /@ {5.25, 7}
```

Comment: Hmm, clever, but I had hoped that a structural solution was available.  I'll accept it since there is no other solution.

Comment: @Shredderroy How do you know there is no other solution?

Comment: Similar to ArgentoSapiens's http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30056, who used `Dot` instead of `Map` to negate the first coordinate.