# Mathematica equivalent to gnuplot's fsteps option?

Tags: plotting

In a `ListLinePlot` I can set `InterpolationOrder -> 0` to get the equivalent of gnuplot's `steps` option, where the stepped line for each two points steps at the second point.  Is there a Mma equivalent to gnuplot's `fsteps` option, where the stepped line for each two points steps at the first point?  (In tikz terminology, I want `|-` instead of `-|` to connect successive points.)

Example application: Verhulst diagrams.

**Edit 1:**

Answers to the question referenced by @MarcoB show that `ListLinePlot` with `InterpolationOrder->0` constructs a standard Manhatten path (alternating horizontal and vertical segments between points). This is equivalent to gnuplot's `steps` option.  I'm after the equivalent of gnuplot's `fsteps` option: alternating vertical and horizontal segments.

To be clear: I am not asking how to produce this plot by creating new data through list manipulations.  (See posts on cobweb plots with Mma for that.)  I'm looking for built-in Mma functionality.  (I accept that this may not exist.)

Edit 2:

```
logisticPath = NestList[2.75*#*(1 - #) &, 0.4, 10]
ListStepPlot[Transpose[{logisticPath, logisticPath}], "Left", 
 PlotRange -> All,
 Prolog -> Line[{{0.4, 0.4}, {0.8, 0.8}}]]
```

Produces
[image: cobweb plot (almost)]

This is almost right.  I just need to get rid of that initial segment, which is outside the data.  What I want looks like this (using the same data):

```
cobwebPoints = Partition[Riffle[logisticPath, logisticPath], 2, 1]
ListLinePlot[cobwebPoints, PlotRange -> All,
 Prolog -> {Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: cobweb plot]

Comment: Strongly related: [How can the behavior of InterpolationOrder->0 be controlled?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30055/27951)

Comment: @MarcoB I think the answers to your referenced question shows that my first sentence is correct but does not explain how to get `fsteps` behavior. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Alan, I think @MichaelE2's answer in that post does provide you a method to get the `fsteps` behavior, at least as far as I understand what that behavior is. Take a look at my answer below, and let me know if I am misunderstanding. If, however, by "built-in MMA functionality" you mean an option to `ListLinePlot`, then the answer is in fact negative. However, you could just start considering Michael's helper functions "built-in" from now on :-)

Comment: Mathematica v10.2 (just released) brings a new function: [`ListStepPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStepPlot.html). See the `step` argument, which can take `Right`, `Left` and `Center` values.

Comment: @kirma Had I seen that comment I might not have joined in voting to close.  I think that would make an excellent answers that is appropriate here but not for the other question.  If you would like to post that as an answer I shall reopen this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'll write my answer in a moment if you reopen the question.

Comment: @kirma Done.  Sorry for the wait.

Comment: @kirma  This looks to be very close to what I'm looking for.  In contrast to other suggestions, it seems not to sort on the x-values, correct? (I don't have 10.2.)  That is important for say a Verhulst diagram.  If that's right, my only quibble is that there seems to be a little extra bit of line before the first point.  Not sure why WRI finds that a good idea ...  Can it be turned off?

Comment: @Alan My answer is below; I'm not sure about your requirements. If it is not what you wanted, tell me what should be different!

Comment: @kirma  Your answer is helpful.  I was trying to ask two questions.  i. Let `x= NestList[2.75*#*(1 - #) &, 0.4, 5]` and then `ListStepPlot[Transpose[{x,x},Left]`.  Does it produce a cobweb?    ii. When I look at your posted answer, I seem to see a little segment before the first point, right?  Can we somehow not draw that?

Comment: @Alan Your `NestList` makes no sense - is there something (a list) missing there? Line segment on the right... that is probably some sort of a bug. Maybe WRI guys can do something about it!

Comment: @kirma The `NestList` command works fine.  See the edited question, which now illustrates the problem I'm having with your otherwise excellent suggestion to try `ListStepPlot`.

Answer (score 4):

Fresh v10.2 introduces `ListStepPlot` which provides just the right facility for this task:

```
pts = {{1.81515, 1.46912}, {4.99276, 1.87137}, {9.12065, 
    6.83238}, {9.9288, 5.30858}, {5.6387, 4.30558}, {4.45562, 
    6.44036}, {0.0721842, 9.82819}, {2.88155, 4.80602}, {7.01912, 
    9.91699}, {0.277599, 5.36962}};

ListStepPlot[SortBy[First][pts], Left, Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

> [image]

Comment: I was going to suggest this. +1

Answer (score 1):

Alan, I think you can use Michael's `stepFunctions` from the answer I linked to in the comments to solve your problem. Here is a link to MichaelE2's original answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30103/27951. Below is an adaptation to your problem using the `step*` functions defined in Michael's original answer. Note that this approach requires **no modification** to your existing points.

---

First of all, let's have some random points to play with:

```
pts = {{1.81515, 1.46912}, {4.99276, 1.87137}, {9.12065, 6.83238}, {9.9288, 5.30858}, 
       {5.6387, 4.30558}, {4.45562, 6.44036}, {0.0721842, 9.82819}, {2.88155, 4.80602}, 
       {7.01912, 9.91699}, {0.277599, 5.36962}};

ListLinePlot[
 SortBy[First][pts],
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> All,
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point@pts}
]
```

[image: native ListLinePlot behavior]

Above is the native behavior of `InterpolationOrder -> 0` that is undesirable to you in this case.

---

It seems to me that **the function you are looking for is** `stepFloor` in the post linked above. You use it as follows:

```
Plot[
 stepFloor[pts][x], {x, 0, 11},
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point@pts}
]
```

[image: stepFloor result]

---

You can also compare all the functions Michael had proposed. Note that `stepCeiling` repoduces the behavior of the native `InterpolationOrder -> 0` in `ListLinePlot`.

```
original = ListLinePlot[
   Sort@pts,
   InterpolationOrder -> 0,
   Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point@pts},
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[
     {Blue, Directive[Black, Dashed], Directive[Darker@Green, Dashed], Directive[Darker@Red, Dashed]},
     {"original", "stepFloor", "stepCeiling", "stepNearest"}
     ]
  ];

floor = Plot[stepFloor[pts][x], {x, -1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Black}];
ceiling = Plot[stepCeiling[pts][x], {x, -1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Darker@Green}];
nearest = Plot[stepNearest[pts][x], {x, -1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Darker@Red}];

Show[original, floor, ceiling, nearest]
```

[image: compare all stepFunctions]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply shift the data:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, -1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 3/2}};
ListLinePlot[ data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
ListLinePlot[ 
   Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], 
     Append[data[[All, 2]][[2 ;;]], data[[-1, 2]]]}], 
        InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]