# Step plot with log-log scale

Tags: plotting, graphics, logarithmic-scale

Anyone know how to impose a log scale on both the $x$ and $y$ axes after using `ListStepPlot`?

There's nothing special about the data set I've used, just a list of 15 ordered pairs that I need to display in a histogram-like manner in a log-log graph.  Below is a picture of the graph that I've created, but I can't find any graphics options that will let me show this in a log-log scale.

[image]

Comment: `ListLogLogPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, Joined -> True, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Axis]`

Comment: Is it a separate question or related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110116/y-axis-ticks-disappeared)?

Comment: And regarding `InterpolationOrder->0`  find very useful discussion [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30055/how-can-the-behavior-of-interpolationorder-0-be-controlled)

Comment: Have you tried `ListStepPlot[yourdata, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]`?

Comment: @MarcoB that's new in v10.4. :)

Comment: @rcol, I believe, scaling functions work in earlier versions, just aren't documented and syntax highlighting sometimes makes them red.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP not for `ListStepPlot` that was 10.4.

Comment: @rcollyer It is working for me right now in version 10.2 It gives an error message, but works as expected.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP really? Well for some definition of works. Yes, you get logarithmic ticks, but other effects like the correct plot range and placement of the axes is not quite there prior to 10.4.

Comment: @rcollyer Indeed, you are forced to think in terms of the `Log` of the coordinates, where the axis is placed at `{0,0}`, which corresponds to what the ticks mark as `{1,1}`. This is the case for many `LogPlot` `LogLinearPlot` and related functions, that internally work with linear coordinates, especially obvious, when one starts to spelunk the ticks functions in the ``Charting` `` context.

Answer (score 5):

In version 10.4 the use of `ScalingFunctions` has finally been documented with `ListStepPlot` (as mentioned by [@rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/52/rcollyer) in comments). It seems to work fine to do what you want.

```
SeedRandom[20160315]

ListStepPlot[
  RandomReal[{0, 0.1}, 15], DataRange -> {0, 19},
  Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
  GridLines -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I noticed that you posted [another similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110116/27951) regarding the disappearance of ticks on the log vertical axis. Since `ListStepPlot` was introduced in 10.2, you must have either version 10.2 or 10.3, but possibly not 10.4. Perhaps you would be able to upgrade. In any case, it would be best if you **shared the exact code that is giving your trouble**.

Comment: The same code gives less than pretty, but quite equivalent output here on version 10.2. It's mainly troubled by the Filling option, but a setting of `-10` puts it back to normal.