# How to plot a list to look like step function?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, piecewise

Suppose I have the following simple list.

```
l = {0,2,5,9,14};
```

I want to to make a plot that looks like the figure below.

I.e. I want to have a horizontal line between all the numbers in the list that increases by 1 unit in vertical height between the numbers aswell, so it looks more or less like a staircase.
[image: list step function]

How can I do it? I've tried Discreteplot and kinda works, the only thing is that the axes are inverted and I can't add vertical lines that connects with the horizontal lines like in the figure.

Comment: I don't understand why it is so difficult to see that only one of the answers below reproduces the OP's figure. Yet the wrong answers have garnered five upvotes altogether so far.  Makes me think this is a deeper question than it first appeared to me. (+1)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
l = {0, 2, 5, 9, 14};
a0 = Total[UnitStep[t - l]] - 1;
Plot[a0, {t, First[l], Last[l]}, Exclusions -> None, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried the different solutions given in this thread and this seems like the solution with the least computational time required.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to make it is `ListLinePlot` with option `InterpolationOrder`:

```
l = {0,2,5,9,14};
ListLinePlot[l, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {-5, 17}}]
```

The generated plot looks like bellow:

[image: step function plot]

### Revision

Thanks @Michael E2 for reminding me. I misunderstand @Turbotanten at first. Bellow is my new revision.

```
data = Thread[{{0, 2, 5, 9, 14}, Range[0, 4]}];
ListLinePlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

To eliminate the right most vertical line:

```
ListLinePlot[data /. {x_, y_} /; x == Max[l] -> {x, 3}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Why does your domain run from `1` to `5`, while the OP's runs from `0` to `14` on the same data?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for reminding. But I could not eliminate the right most vertical line elegantly.

Comment: I suppose one could clip that vertical line with `Clip[]`: `data = Thread[{{0, 2, 5, 9, 14}, Clip[Range[0, 4], {0, 3}]}]`...

Answer (score 8):

Also, if you have a version 10.2 or above, you could use `ListStepPlot`

```
Module[
 {l},
 l = {0, 2, 5, 9, 14};
 ListStepPlot[l]
 ]
```

**EDIT**
*Reversing the axis*

```
Module[
 {l},
 l = {0, 2, 5, 9, 14};
 ListStepPlot[l, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Identity}]
 ]
```

Comment: Yes I actually have version 11.2. Is it possible to invert the axes though?  Because I would like to have the unit steps on the vertical y-axis.

Comment: @Turbotanten see edit above :)

Comment: Why does your domain run from `1` to `6`, while the OP's runs from `0` to `14` on the same data?  See Carl Woll's answer for a fix.

Answer (score 4):

One needs to use the second documented form of [`ListStepPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStepPlot) for this:

```
ListStepPlot[
    Thread[{{0,2,5,9,14},Range[0,4]}],
    PlotRange->{{0,14},{0,5}},
    PlotStyle->Red
]
```

[image]

**Update**

You could also use [`StepFunction`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156925/45431) from my answer to [(30055)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30055/45431). Here is an example:

```
sf = StepFunction[Thread[{{0,2,5,9,14},Range[0,4]}], Right];

Plot[sf[t], {t, 0, 14}, PlotStyle->Directive[Thick, Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Now there's another correct answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Some other ways.  Use `Exclusions -> None` in the first case to get joined steps.

```
Plot[Length@l*CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[l], x] - 1, {x, Min@l, Max@l}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[LengthWhile[l, # <= x &], {x, Min@l, Max@l}]
Plot[Count[l, y_ /; y <= x], {x, Min@l, Max@l}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Less simple, more direct:

```
xx = l;
yy = Range[0, Length@l - 2];
Graphics[
 {Red, AbsoluteThickness[1.6], 
  Line@ Riffle[{Most@xx, yy}\[Transpose], {Rest@xx, yy}\[Transpose]]},
 Options@ListPlot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it that I came up with

```
l = {0, 2, 5, 9, 14};
v[x_] := Sum[HeavisideTheta[x - l[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[l]}];
Plot[v[x], {x, 0, Last[l]}, Exclusions -> None, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick]}]
```

Comment: In general tho, `HeavisideTheta[]` is more intended for pure *symbolic* work rather than numerical evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

One always has the option of constructing a `Piecewise[]` function directly:

```
l = {0, 2, 5, 9, 14};

f[x_] = Piecewise[Transpose[{Range[0, Length[l] - 2],
                             #1 < x <= #2 & @@@ Partition[l, 2, 1]}], Indeterminate]
```

(This version is right-continuous, but it should not be too hard to modify if you prefer a left-continuous version.)