# How do I transform my results? List-manipulation? Interpolation?

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting, interpolation, simulation

I have the data

```
{{0, 10, 10}, {0.01829, 12, 10}, {0.0523236, 11, 10}, {0.0616182, 11, 9}, 
{0.0860192, 10, 9}, {0.37603, 12, 9}, {0.405224, 11, 9}, {0.415151, 11, 8}, 
{0.453143, 13, 8}, {0.481562, 12, 8}, {0.482285, 11, 8}, {0.490412, 10, 8}, 
{0.492742, 10, 7}, {0.558841, 9, 7}, {0.602336, 8, 7}, {0.683204, 8, 6}, 
{0.738865, 9, 7}, {0.766657, 9, 9}, {0.780627, 9, 8}, {0.900705, 9, 10}, 
{0.905607, 9, 9}, {0.926086, 9, 8}, {1.00437, 9, 7}, {1.01303, 11, 7}, 
{1.06747, 10, 7}, {1.07523, 9, 7}, {1.33235, 8, 7}, {1.51981, 7, 8}, 
{1.61516, 6, 8}, {1.66955, 6, 7}, {1.95405, 5, 7}, {2.04023, 5, 6}, 
{2.04605, 5, 5}, {2.23846, 5, 4}, {2.25056, 4, 4}, {2.27559, 3, 4}, 
{2.5348, 2, 5}, {2.55095, 2, 6}, {2.71852, 2, 5}, {2.95299, 4, 5}, 
{3.23626, 6, 5}}
```

which represents {time, amount1, amount2}. Changes to each amount only happens at the times stated in the results.

How do I transform my data so it tells me the two amounts for discrete moments in time?

For example, for steps of 0.5, the data would be the following

```
{0, 10, 10}, {0.5, 10, 7}, {1.0, 9, 8}, {1.5, 8, 7}, 
{2.0, 5, 7}, {2.5, 3, 4}, {3.0, 4, 5}
```

For example, for steps of 1, the data would be the following

```
{0, 10, 10}, {1, 9, 8}, {2, 5, 7}, {3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to try `Nearest[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Can use `TimeSeries` and `TimeSeriesResample`:

```
pts = Dataset[{{0, 10, 10},...,{3.23626, 6, 5}}];
```

Wrap cols 2 and 3 in a List and then `TimeSeries`

```
ts = pts[All,{1,{2,3}}][TimeSeries];
```

Resample:

```
ts // TimeSeriesResample[#, 0.5] & // #["Path"] &
```

> {{0., {10., 10.}}, {0.5, {9.8902, 7.}}, {1., {9., 
>      7.05582}}, {1.5, {7.10568, 7.89432}}, {2., {5., 
>      6.46681}}, {2.5, {2.13425, 4.86575}}, {3., {4.33191, 5.}}}

Note, from ref page:

> "By default, values at intermediate times are computed using
>   first-order interpolation"

Other interpolation methods are available, eg:

```
ts // TimeSeriesResample[#, 0.5, 
    ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", 
      InterpolationOrder -> 0}] & // #["Path"] &
```

> {{0., {10, 10}}, {0.5, {10, 7}}, {1., {9, 8}}, {1.5, {8, 7}}, {2., {5,
>       7}}, {2.5, {3, 4}}, {3., {4, 5}}}

Comment: This method will not give me integers values will it? @alancalvitti

Comment: @Mlo27, it does if the input values are integers and `InterpolationOrder->0` is chosen - see last line in my answer. (Obviously the time values you wanted are resampled at 0.5 so are not going to be integers).

Comment: The time values do not have the be integers. I just need the output to always be integers. Will this method allow that? @alancalvitti

Comment: @Mlo27, yes, as I said, read the last line of output. You can use `Flatten` to get the same verbatim format as in your Q, but that will interfere with any subsequent `TimeSeries` operations.

Comment: Sorry didn’t see that last bit. Thanks for the advice, I’ll give it a try later on :D

Comment: Just gave this a try and it seems to work ok. How would I modify it to work for list of results (n sets on results in a list) @alancalvitti

Comment: @Mlo27, try `(* output *) // Flatten[#,1]&`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modification of `StepFunction` from my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156925/45431) to [How can the behavior of InterpolationOrder->0 be controlled?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30055/45431):

```
StepFunction[data_] := Module[{sdata, nf}, sdata=Sort@data;
    nf = Nearest[sdata[[All,1]] -> "Index"];
    StepFunction[nf, sdata[[All,1]], sdata[[All, {2,3}]], {-1,0}]
]

StepFunction[nf_NearestFunction, x_, y_, clip_][pt_List] := With[
    {near = nf[pt][[All,1]]},
    Join[
        List/@pt,
        y[[Clip[near + Clip[Sign[Subtract[pt, x[[near]]]], clip], {1, Length[x]}]]],
        2
    ]
]
StepFunction[nf_NearestFunction, x_, y_, clip_][pt_] := With[
    {near = First@nf[pt]},
    Prepend[
        y[[Clip[near + Clip[Sign[Subtract[pt, x[[near]]]], clip], {1, Length[x]}]]],
        pt
    ]
]
```

For your data:

```
sf = StepFunction[{
    {0,10,10},{0.01829,12,10},{0.0523236,11,10},{0.0616182,11,9},{0.0860192,10,9},
    {0.37603,12,9},{0.405224,11,9},{0.415151,11,8},{0.453143,13,8},{0.481562,12,8},
    {0.482285,11,8},{0.490412,10,8},{0.492742,10,7},{0.558841,9,7},{0.602336,8,7},
    {0.683204,8,6},{0.738865,9,7},{0.766657,9,9},{0.780627,9,8},{0.900705,9,10},
    {0.905607,9,9},{0.926086,9,8},{1.00437,9,7},{1.01303,11,7},{1.06747,10,7},
    {1.07523,9,7},{1.33235,8,7},{1.51981,7,8},{1.61516,6,8},{1.66955,6,7},{1.95405,5,7},
    {2.04023,5,6},{2.04605,5,5},{2.23846,5,4},{2.25056,4,4},{2.27559,3,4},{2.5348,2,5},
    {2.55095,2,6},{2.71852,2,5},{2.95299,4,5},{3.23626,6,5}
}];
```

Then:

```
sf[Range[0, 3, .5]]
sf[Range[0, 3]]
```

> {{0., 10, 10}, {0.5, 10, 7}, {1., 9, 8}, {1.5, 8, 7}, {2., 5, 7}, {2.5, 3, 
>     4}, {3., 4, 5}}
>
> {{0, 10, 10}, {1, 9, 8}, {2, 5, 7}, {3, 4, 5}}

Comment: This method isn't producing an output @Carl Woll

Comment: @Mlo27 If you are using M10 or earlier, replace "Index" with Automatic.

Comment: @CarlWoll How can I modify your code for this question. Suggested method is very slow for large data. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172298/sample-the-data-with-equal-step-size