# How to Create an Efficient Step Function from Data

Tags: function-construction, nearest

I have list of rules from where a DateListStepPlot can be created to visualize the problem:

```
dateToPopulationRules = {DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}] -> 5, DateObject[{2019, 2, 1}] -> 10, DateObject[{2019, 2, 13}] -> 6, DateObject[{2019, 4, 4}] -> 1};
DateListStepPlot[List @@@ dateToPopulationRules, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {None, "Population"}]
```

[image]

I want to create an efficient function for population using a huge instance of `dateToPopulationRules`.  Here's my poor implementation:

```
Clear[population];
population[dateObj_] := 0;
Table[
  With[{dateLim = First@dpr, pop = Last@dpr},
   population[dateObj_] := Condition[pop, dateObj >= dateLim]
   ]
  , {dpr, dateToPopulationRules}];
```

An example showing how the population function works is below.  You may want to see `DownValues@population` in case that helps understanding my code.

```
In[11]:= population[DateObject[{2019, 3, 1}]]
Out[11]= 5
```

Although this approach is effective I don't think is the most efficient.  I would like to see another solution using a Nearest function or other function that can handle large data sets efficiently.

Comment: If you want it to be efficient, it's probably best to convert the dates to `AbsoluteTime`. Simple numbers will beat date objects in performance most of the time. You can use `Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]` to get the interpolation behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Wow! It looks so obvious now. Still, it would be good to see the implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation) as suggested @Sjoerd, for example:

```
data = List @@@ dateToPopulationRules /. d_DateObject :> AbsoluteTime[d];

p = Interpolation[
    data . {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}},
    InterpolationOrder->0
] @* Minus;
```

where I need to use a double negation to get the end point behavior correct. Visualization:

```
Plot[
    p[x],
    {x, AbsoluteTime@DateObject[{2019,1,1}], AbsoluteTime@DateObject[{2019,6,1}]},
    PlotRange->{0,10.5},
    Ticks->{
        Charting`DateTicksFunction[Automatic, DateTicksFormat -> {Automatic}],
        Automatic
    },
    Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[data]} 
]
```

[image]

If you want a faster function, you could try using [`StepFunction`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156925/45431) from [How can the behavior of InerpolationOrder->0 be controlled](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30055/45431):

```
q = StepFunction[data, Right];
Plot[
    q[x],
    {x, AbsoluteTime@DateObject[{2019,1,1}], AbsoluteTime@DateObject[{2019,6,1}]},
    PlotRange->{0,10.5},
    Ticks->{
        Charting`DateTicksFunction[Automatic, DateTicksFormat -> {Automatic}],
        Automatic
    },
    Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[data]} 
]
```

[image]

Speed comparison:

```
times = RandomReal[
    AbsoluteTime /@ {DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2019, 4, 1}]},
    10^5
];

r1 = p[times]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = q[times]; //RepeatedTiming

r1===r2
```

> {0.14, Null}
>
> {0.0072, Null}
>
> True

So, using `StepFunction` is almost 20 times faster.

Comment: Excellent!  I assume your StepFunction will eventually be added to the Wolfram Language.

Comment: @ArielSepulveda I'm planning to add it as a ResourceFunction, no idea whether somebody might add a kernel function to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You may use[`TimeSeries`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) with the [`ResamplingMethod`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResamplingMethod.html) option.

```
tsPop = TimeSeries[List @@@ dateToPopulationRules,
  ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`InterpolationOrder -> 0` repeats prior value until new value is defined.

```
tsPop[DateObject /@ {{2019, 1, 30}, {2019, 2, 1}}]
```

> ```
> {5, 10}
> ```

Plot with [`DateListStepPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListStepPlot.html).

```
DateListStepPlot[tsPop, Mesh -> Full]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very useful and a new window opened into TimeSeries.  Thanks!  Based on a simple test using RepeatedTiming q function based on StepFunction seems to be near one order faster than tsPop.