# interpolation with order zero seems to be shifted to the right

Tags: interpolation

I'm trying to set up an `InterpolatingFunction`, that would be a step function.  I have a series of `x` and `f` values.  I took an example from the Mathematica documentation (under `InterpolationOrder`) and it doesn't work the way I expected.  The example itself shows what I expected.  But making a function out of that data does not do what I expect.

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {6, 0}};
ListLinePlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

This produced picture of a step function showing what I expected.  However when I used that same data and made a function I got something unexpected.

```
f=Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder->0]
f[0] gave me 2, not 0
f[1] also gave me 2 (which I expected)
f[1.1] gave me 4
```

Am I doing something wrong?  I want f[x] to be 2 for 1 <= x < 3

**EDIT**
The answer from ArgentoSapiens in [How can the behavior of InterpolationOrder->0 be controlled?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30055/how-can-the-behavior-of-interpolationorder-0-be-controlled) fixes my problem.

Comment: @CarlWoll Maybe, there's a lot there!  Thanks, I'll go through it.

Comment: Look up the help of Interpolation. Under Options/InterpolationOrder the first example has InterpolationOrder->0 and shows, that the first data point is neglected.