# What Kind of plot is this one?

Tags: plotting, graphics

What kind of plot is this one? How to build one of these? This is a dataset with bins with different sizes. [image: Plot taken from http://go.warwick.ac.uk/wrap/77362]

Plot taken from http://go.warwick.ac.uk/wrap/77362

Comment: If you didn't make this yourself, you should mention where you got this image from.

Comment: Sorry, I though that I putted it. I took it from that thesis: http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/77362/

Comment: It looks like these: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30055/how-can-the-behavior-of-interpolationorder-0-be-controlled It also looks like these: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html

Comment: It would be easier to help, if a dataset was given.

Comment: [`ListStepPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListStepPlot.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would go about it this way:

Create some data:

```
data = Table[1 10^4 + -1 10^6 E^(-0.594 t) Sin[-0.2 t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}];
```

create somes lines:

```
lines = Table[InfiniteLine[{ {0, Log[1 10^i]}, {1, Log[1 10^i]}}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

Plot:

```
ListLogPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, Epilog -> {{Black, Dashed, lines}} ]
```

[image]