# Set user-defined uneven step size in ListStepPlot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the following data as steps:

```
Ydata={2,4,6,8,10};
Xdata={2,8,18,34,64};
halfbinsize={2,4,6,10,20};
```

I want to include the bin-size (or half-bin-size) into account. So in this case the first bin will be `dx=[0-4]` with a central value at `Xcentral=2`. For the next bin `dx=[4-12]` with central value `Xcentral=8`. Similarly for the next bins `dx=[12-24], Xcentral=18`, `dx=[24-44], Xcentral=34`, `dx=[44-84], Xcentral=64`...

Now with `ListStepPlot` I can have a bin-distribution, however, it seems like it takes the steps-sizes automatically.

```
ListStepPlot[TemporalData[{Ydata},{Xdata}],
Center,
PlotRange->{{-10.0,90.0},{0,12}},
Mesh->Full,
Frame->True,
FrameTicks->{
{#,#}&@(Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity},"TicksLength"->{0.03,0.015}][##,{5,11}]&),
{#,#}&@(Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity},"TicksLength"->{0.03,0.015}][##,{11,11}]&)}
]
```

[image]

As it is shown, although the central values are shown correctly, the steps (or bins) are rather different. For example for the first bin, it takes the bin-size to be `6` (probably it just looks at two successive x-data and from there it derives the bin-size automatically, in this case, `8-2=6` and distributes `6` equally around `2`), and thus plots as `dx=[-1,5]` with `Xcentral=2`.

My question is: **How should I force `ListStepPlot` to use user-defined bins with correct central value?**

Comment: [A related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30055).

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Ydata = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
Xdata = {2, 8, 18, 34, 64};
halfbinsize = {2, 4, 6, 10, 20};
```

Using [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) with [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html)

```
ListPlot[
 Transpose[{Around @@@
    Transpose[{Xdata, halfbinsize}], Ydata}],
 PlotRange -> {{-10.0, 90.0}, {0, 12}},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {
   {#, #} &@(Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity},
        "TicksLength" -> {0.03, 0.015}][##, {5, 11}] &),
   {#, #} &@(Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity},
        "TicksLength" -> {0.03, 0.015}][##, {11, 11}] &)}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: So with `ListStepPlot` it is not that straightforward for this purpose? The reason I wanted to stick to that is, that it is very easy there to use other features like having a histogram-like or step-like plot, filling the area between two sets of Ydata very easily using `Filling` etc.