# Resample $(x,y)$ data using nearest-left approach

Tags: interpolation, data

I have some data of the form `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ..., {xn, yn}}`.  It is already sorted by `x` values.  I am looking for a simple way to resample it and obtain `{{rx1, ry1}, {rx2, ry2}, ...}` for a given set of `{rx1, rx2, ...}` coordinates, in such a way that the `ry` value corresponding to an `rx` will be the same as the `y` value of the nearest left `x` neighbour of `rx`.

Suppose the data is

```
data={{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}, {4.5, 5}}
```

Then I am basically looking to take values from the function plotted below, for an arbitrary set of `x` values:

```
ListPlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}, {4.5, 5}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Is there anything built in for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can the behavior of InterpolationOrder->0 be controlled?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30055/how-can-the-behavior-of-interpolationorder-0-be-controlled). Especially the [last answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30056/36508) seems to provide an "almost-builtin" solution by negating the x axis twice: `Plot[Interpolation[{-#, #2} & @@@ InterpolationOrder -> 0][-x], {x, 0, 4.6}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}]`

Comment: @LukasLang Maybe I've been writing too much C recently, but I found it frustrating that this task would be very straightfoward in a procedural language, requiring a single loop through the arrays. But in Mathematica the performance would be bad, and `Nearest` (i.e. a binary search for each point) feels like a huge overkill ...

Comment: Yeah, this is certainly a case where a procedural approach is way more suited than a "Mathematica-style" approach (you could of course just implement the procedural approach in MMA and compile it if needed, but that's not really the point). I tried to come up with an elegant & efficient MMA-style solution, but I couldn't really think of something. I think I've seen this type of problem before, and I feel that the need for some kind of iteration state doesn't lend itself to functional solutions. The closest is something based on one of the `Fold*` variants, but those quickly become unreadable.