# List plot joined with stair steps instead of diagonal lines

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

What's a simple way to plot a list of points so that they're joined with stair steps instead of straight lines between the points?

I'd imagine something like...

```
stairStepListPlot[{{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}}]
```

...would produce a flat line from {0,0} to {1,0}, then a vertical line from {1,0} to {1,1} and so on.

Can you find a concise way of producing such a plot?

Comment: `ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Joined -> True]`

Comment: Possible duplicates: [30055](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30055), [864](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/864)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot.html) can do this with the option [`InterpolationOrder -> 0`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolationOrder.html)

```
ListPlot[
   {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}},
   InterpolationOrder -> 0,
   Joined -> True]
```